# Where did Captain Cold get his freezing power from, when he stopped using his gun in the new 52

Tags: dc, the-flash, the-new-52

I can't remember the title, but in the new 52 flash book, NOT Rebirth, but something else. Captain Cold is using his powers like Killer Frost. The book ends with him trying to kill Barry for supposedly causing a blackout, thus restricting his sister from getting medical attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Captain Cold alongside a few other rogues were fused with their weapons so that their powers were written into their DNA
[image: DNA]

He had these powers until the gun was stripped from his DNA by Deathstorm in Forever Evil limited series.

Comment: The artist is certainly the same, perfect.